# Populating dictionary (from irregular patterned text)

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm a beginner to programming and I have a question from my assignment.
with a given txt file, with the following format, I'm suppose to organize them into 2 dictionaries,

```
last name, first name
network
last name, first name
last name, first name

last name, first name
network
last name, first name

last name, first name
last name, first name
last name, first name
last name, first name

last name, first name
network
last name, first name
```

the very first name of each chunk is the profile's name (person)
and the rest of the names below are profile's friends.
(the first line of each chunk is always the profile's name, first name may have more than 1 word, and networks will never have comma in it)
each profile has irregular number of lines and some profiles have network some don't.

I am asked to create 2 dictionaries, person_to_friends(which has person as the key and friends to values), and person_to_network(which has person as the key and networks to values)

result should look like below

> person to friends":{'Jay Pritchett': ['Gloria Pritchett', 'Manny Delgado', 'Claire Dunphy'], 'Claire Dunphy': ['Phil Dunphy', 'Mitchell Pritchett', 'Jay Pritchett'], 'Manny Delgado': ['Gloria Pritchett', 'Jay Pritchett', 'Luke Dunphy']}
>
> person to networks":{'Phil Dunphy': ['Real Estate Association'], 'Claire Dunphy': ['Parent Teacher Association'], 'Manny Delgado': ['Chess Club'], 'Mitchell Pritchett': ['Law Association']}

I am having trouble writing a code that tells python to populate the dictionary.
Common pattern for [person] could be that it is always the line after an empty line.  However the very first [person] is at the beginning of the file so there is no empty line before it..
I have come to a problem where if I use for loop, I will end up with every other line being added into [person] since I tried to put

```
person = line
```

at the beginning to take into account to the fact that the very first name has no empty line before it.

I have tried to use both readlines and readline but I get stuck for each method.  I'm wondering if you guys can help me with it.  Thank you!

Comment: you need to show some code, or else this is just doing your assignment for yourself ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_groups(lines):
    group = []
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            group.append(line)
        else:
            if group:
                yield group
                group = []
    if group:
        yield group

with open("myfile.txt") as inf:
    for group in get_groups(inf):
        # now process group!
```

Answer (score 0):

When you encounter a non-blank line, you need to process it based on whether the previous line was blank or not.  The first line in the file gets handled as if it were preceded by a blank.  Correct?

Create a boolean variable to keep track of when the previous line was blank.  Something like this (assuming file is already open and ready for reading):

```
was_blank = True
for line in file:
    if line:   # evaluates True if the line is not blank.
        if was_blank:
            new_name(line)
        else:
            process_the_line(line)
        was_blank = False
    else:
        was_blank = True
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, and I don't have any python experience... but this pseudocode may help:

1. create an empty array/object to store person_to_friends
2. create an empty array/object to store person_to_networks
3. write a function that splits a string by comma, reverses the parts, and puts them back together
4. read the contents of that file into a string
5. split the string by two newline characters to get each profile "\n\n"
6. iterate over each profile
7. split the profile into lines by a newline character "\n"
8. use your function from #3 to reverse the first line
9. check the second line for a comma, if not, add first line and second line to person_to_networks object
10. iterate remaining lines, checking for comma and reversing, adding to temporarary object/array
11. add line one plus temporary object/array to person_to_friends object/array
12. hand in homework, enjoy success, eat pizza